# How do I compute $ \int \frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate the following expression with respect to x...I used UV rule of integration, but it failed...can anyone guide me with the right approach?
$$\int\frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}dx$$

Answer (score 8):

Enforce the substitution $u=1+xe^x$.  Then, $du=(x+1)e^x\,dx$ and the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{(u-1)u^2}\,du$$

Using partial fraction expansion, we have

$$\int \frac{1}{(u-1)u^2}\,du=\frac1u +\log|1-u|-\log |u|+C$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{1+xe^x}+\log (xe^x)-\log(1+xe^x)+C\\\\
&=x+\frac{1}{1+xe^x}+\log x-\log (1+xe^x)+C
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}dx=\int\frac{(x+1)e^x}{xe^x(1+xe^x)^2}dx$$

Set $1+xe^x=u$

then use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)